# Windows Service written in D7, cannot be run under WinServer2008 64 bit after restart

Tags: delphi, windows-server-2008, delphi-7

I have written a post several months ago regarding the problem I have been fighting with.
Here was the link:

[0x0eedfade kernelbase.dll faulting module in d7 windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148853/0x0eedfade-kernelbase-dll-faulting-module-in-d7-windows-service)

Generally the problem is that the Windows service written in D7 for the first time starts ok and works perfectly but in the time when I have to restart it (e.g. after several days) , I cannot do it.

Today I have included madexcept to the executable and I got during startup:

```
compiled with     : Delphi 7
madExcept version : 3.0l
callstack crc     : $dbabc0aa, $f5cfd533, $f5cfd533
exception number  : 1
exception class   : EOutOfResources
exception message : Error creating window class.

main thread ($c88):
004a7419 +09d ServiceTest.exe Forms                  6322 +20 TApplication.CreateHandle
004a7206 +1a6 ServiceTest.exe Forms                  6250 +32 TApplication.Create
00493fc3 +10b ServiceTest.exe Controls              10924 +10 InitControls
0049411b +02f ServiceTest.exe Controls              10943  +2 initialization
004048c0 +044 ServiceTest.exe System                          InitUnits
00404926 +03a ServiceTest.exe System                          @StartExe
00407392 +03a ServiceTest.exe SysInit                         @InitExe
004ed991 +011 ServiceTest.exe ServiceTest    62  +0 initialization
75f13675 +010 kernel32.dll
```

Well as far as I remember it doesn't even go to begin end section of the project file.
I am just curious whether the system is running out of resources but:
system handles are on the good level, memory as well.

Any suggestion what still Can i do?

I cannot restart the production sever everytime I get this error and cannot restart the application.

Comment: could it be that you have memory leaks? I haven't used madexcept, but I think it will log the errors, so in this case, windows goes crazy about the fact that there aren't resources available to give to your service... also, please check if other application/service is using too many resources

Comment: @DorinDuminica Yep, it does sound like leaks are the problem. madExcept doesn't report memory or resource leaks, but the memory manager c/should. However, a leak is not a leak (certainly can't be concluded to be a leak) until the process exits and a restart of the service doesn't end the process in which it runs. So it is up to careful manual checking of all constructors and destructors and/or circular references of interfaced (ref counted) object instances.

Comment: What is interesting, when I run the service from the service console then I get the error, when I run as a standalone app, the error is not raised...

Comment: Running it from the console? How? Do you use `net start <your service>` or just the exe name?

Comment: @Marjan Venema I just don't get it why this cannot be run again, which seems to me I can exclude all my program's code. Literally when the process exists, most allocated resources should be free.

Comment: From the Services window (list of system services) I get the error. The other option is to just launch executable file and it succeed. Furthermore I placed: "exit" after begin in dpr file. So the error occurs actually before my code starts ..

Comment: Without seeing some code I can only guess. Even seeing code, there are a lot of variables that can influence this. `net start <your service>` actually is the same as going to the service manager, locating your service and starting it. Starting the exe directly also results in the service manager being notified, but this may occur later and your service may not be "bothered" by "reportstatus" calls from the SCM during start up.

Comment: Exit right after begin not being reached means the error occurs during loading of required dll's or during processing of initialization sections.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a leak of resources in your application/service.

you need to checkup on, Window Desktop Heap, heres one ms KB article [Out of Memory" error message appears when you have a large number of programs running](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126962).

We have seen very similar issues with services not running or behaving very oddly (things like sockets becoming deaf), and tracked it down to the DesktopHeap becoming filled, the reason it works when running as application is that the desktop heap for applications is MUCH larger than the one used for services.

This Link [Desktop Heap Overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx) explains what its used for.

DHeapMon is a application you can use to monitor the Desktop Heaps and determine if you are leaking (or just using) too many resources.

You need to make sure your services use as few TForms as possible (preferably none).

You can change the size of the Services Desktop Heap in the registry, the links explain how, this can be used to help find issue ( usually reducing it to force fault quicker ), or to increase it if you are using lots of services.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try, currently I got stuck on dheapmon installation, it gives me 124 error and I am trying to solve the problem ..

Comment: Unfortunately after a few hourse I am still unable to install the monitor. I had followed the instruction with downloading the symbols to a new directory. I am always getting 124 error and cannot do anything with that ... Haven't you had such error during installation?

Comment: Only issue we had installing DHeapMon was that the machine it is being installed on needs access to the internet to download the symbol files, we couldn't use use one we had already downloaded.