# Strange 0x0eedfade exception in Delphi multi thread program

Tags: multithreading, delphi, exception, service

I have strange problem with my multi threaded server. It is Windows service and works similar to FTP server managing socket connection to many clients. It was created using Delphi 2006 (Turbo Delphi) and works well on most machines. Unfortunately on some machines it sometimes crashes without any trace from itself (exception should be saved to log, but are not). Sometimes system shows MessageBox (it is not MessageBox from service, but I think it is system MessageBox), but most often I see such information in System EventLog:

```
Application popup: ht_switch.exe - Application Error : The exception unknown software exception (0x0eedfade) occurred in the application at location 0x77e4bef7.
```

In Application EventLog I can see:

```
Faulting application ht_switch.exe, version 1.2.0.2, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.5069, fault address 0x0000bef7.
```

Sometimes such entries are in Application or System EventLog, but nothing happens -- my server works as usually, but sometimes is simply disappears. Then Service Manager reports in EventlLog that my service unexpectedly stopped.

I see no "common" scenario to such problem. It appears on some WinXP, Win2003 and Win2008. All test machines have all MS patches applied.

I have read answers to: [0x0eedfade kernelbase.dll faulting module in d7 windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148853/0x0eedfade-kernelbase-dll-faulting-module-in-d7-windows-service) but I do not use `Dialog` unit.

What can I do to repair it? How to trace such `0x0eedfade` exception?

**EDIT**

I tested for some days my server with both EurekaLog and madExcept.

*EurekaLog*:

Server works without problem. No exception is reported in EventLog. No exception is reported in `%AppData%\EurekaLab s.a.s\EurekaLog\Bug Reports\` (there should be directory for my program, but it was not created -- I don't know if it should be created or if it is an EurekaLog error).

EurekaLog7 have problem with setting "Application Type" to Windows Service. It is known problem and authors works on it. My service compiled with it works on WinXP but was not able to work on Win2003. It simply do not start.

*madExcept*:

Server worked for 4 hours and crashed. I have caught this exception in my thread:

```
EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 7C90100B in module 'ntdll.dll'. Read of address 00000018!!!
```

I haven't noticed any madExcept report on this exception. After this exception one thread was lost with socket in `CLOSE_WAIT` state (other side closed connection). Then I restarted my service and after next few hours it worked without problem.

*disabled EurekaLog and madExcept*:

After 10-30 minutes I see MessageBox with error. But `0x0eedfade` error is cryptic and do not show me any hint on source of the problem. It is also very strange because after displaying such message service works without problem (most of the time).

**Summary od exception interceptors**:

EurekaLog and madExcept are probably good at exceptions raised by Delphi but it seems that change behavior of my service and error magically disappeared or they report exception to place I cannot find.

**EDIT: Problem solved**

After some debugging that lead me to nowhere (Call Stack with very strange places) I resigned from it and started to inspect lastly commited changes. One change was string operation where string (AnsiString) can be of length 64 or 128 (some kind of bit mask). I set 70th character of string that was earlier allocated with `SetLength(buffer, 64)`. That was the problem. I think I would save time by enabling range checking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to trace such 0x0eedfade exception?

This is the code for a Delphi exception. Clearly you are raising a Delphi exception that is not being handled and that is bringing your process down.

You should add madExcept, EurekaLog, JCLDebug or similar to your process. These tools will produce diagnostics reports when your process fails. The most useful part of those reports will be the stack trace at the point of failure. You should be able then to work out where the failure occurs, at the very least, and this usually is enough to work out what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks, I started with EurekaLog, but it seems that newest version of this tool has bug that do not allow to set "VCL Windows Service" project type. But I compiled my service with "Custom settings" project type, started tests and I'm watching what will happen.

Comment: Personally I'm a madExcept user. I've got nothing but praise for that tool.

Comment: On one of test machines my server without such tools reported `0x0eedfade` after 10-15 minutes of tests. With EurekaLog there is no such exception nor log in "Bug Raports" directory. Don't know if now problem disappeared or EurekaLog changed something that "repaired" system or hide error. Now I'm testing it with madExcept.

Comment: After few days of testing it seems that problem is not displaying when I compile my service with EurekaLog or madExcept but I also was not able to find source of the problem. More details in my edited question.

Comment: Force an AV in your service and take a look at the output that ME produces. If you can't find the bug report for an AV that you forced, then you won't find the bug report for the real problem. First of all prove that ME is operating in a way that you understand and that will catch the real fault. Finally, SO is not a place where we guide you through a long debugging process. I think I answered the original question that you asked. You are now asking a different question. It's not fair to keep editing the original question asking more and more.

Comment: I do not agree. My question is the same. I started testing with EurekaLog and madExcept but it seems they do not work in my case. In my threads `Execute` method I have `try..except` and when I forced AV in my thread it was caught and reported by my code: `EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 0050BEE6 in module 'ht_switch.exe'. Read of address 00000000!!!`. Maybe EurekaLog and madExcept works when you do not use `try...except`. With forced AV they did nothing. But I'm not able to intercept `0x0eedfade` exception nor in my code, nor by EurekaLog nor by madExcept.

Comment: I also forced AV in code that starts service (no `try..except`). Service do not start, madExcept have not created report but using ProcessMonitor I see that `C:\WINDOWS\Temp\ht_switch.madExcept` was created and then deleted.

Comment: I think I answered the original question that you asked.

Comment: AV forced in main thread created report with EurekaLog, but the same AV forced in service thread is reported only in my `except` section omitting EurekaLog.

Comment: David, I appreciate your help. Tools you mentioned looks great but they probably works best for regular VCL GUI applications. It seems that `0x0eedfade` exception is very strange and hard to intercept. Maybe fact that this is multithread service makes thing worse. I'm still looking for some help.

Comment: As I said in my answer `0x0eedfade` is the code for a Delphi language exception. It's not remotely strange and it's trivial to intercept. I answered your original question, which was *How to trace such 0x0eedfade exception?* You are now asking about something completely different. We don't do one-on-one debugging sessions on SO. You need to ask a new question. A question about how to use ME or EurekaLog in the context of a service. Either ask here, or ask at the software vendor's forum.

Comment: OK. I will make my service regular VCL application and then if error not disappear I will use tools you advised. Thanks!

Comment: After some debugging that lead me to nowhere (Call Stack with very strange places) I resigned from it and started to inspect lastly commited changes. One change was string operation where string (AnsiString) can be of length 64 or 128 (some kind of bit mask). I set 70th character of string that was earlier allocated with `SetLength(buffer, 64)`. That was the problem. I think I would save time by enabling range checking.

Comment: Yes, range checking is very powerful indeed.