# Borland Delphi 5 and 7: exceptions stop to work

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-7, delphi-5

I faced very strange behavior: after some point in the code exceptions stop to work. This is my test function:

```
procedure vmDbg_TestExceptionsHandling(AMarker: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := UVmDll.DebugPoint(9002, PChar(AMarker)); // #define dbgpnt_HeapCheck  9002
  if i <> 1 then
    ToAppLogger(ll_ERROR, format('  %s->UVmDll.DebugPoint(9002)->heap integrity failure!', [AMarker]));

  //DBG:
  try
    // when Borland RTL space is somehow broken, it will crash here!
    raise Exception.Create('test exceptions#1 /' + AMarker);
  except
    on e: Exception do begin
      ToAppLogger(ll_ERROR, format('  %s->UVmDll.DebugPoint(99)->%s', [AMarker, ExcErrMsg(e)]));
    end;
  end;

  //DBG:
  try
    // inside ScriptVN.dll there is a special handling for point# 99 - it will throw a C++ exception
    UVmDll.DebugPoint(99, PChar(AMarker));
  except
    on e: Exception do begin
      ToAppLogger(ll_ERROR, format('  %s->UVmDll.DebugPoint(99)->%s', [AMarker, ExcErrMsg(e)]));
    end;
  end;

  //DBG:
  try
    // sometimes it may crash here...
    raise Exception.Create('test exceptions#2 /' + AMarker);
  except
    on e: Exception do begin
      ToAppLogger(ll_ERROR, format('  %s->UVmDll.DebugPoint(99)->%s', [AMarker, ExcErrMsg(e)]));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And then use it in my code like this:

```
procedure vmDll_Jira790TestCase;
var
  n: integer;
  ixf: cpp_IInterface;
  rw, rwx, rwd: TRow;
begin
  isJira790Catch := true; 
  vmDbg_TestExceptionsHandling('Jira790TestCase.0'); //<-- here it works fine

  rwd := TRow.CreateDummy;
  vmDbg_TestExceptionsHandling('Jira790TestCase.1'); //<-- here it works fine

  rw := TRow.Create(true);
  vmDbg_TestExceptionsHandling('Jira790TestCase.2'); //<-- here it works fine

  ixf := UVmDll.DataTree__GetContainerInterface(rw.Engine);
  rwx := TRow.CreateForIxf(ixf); // <-- it crashes on leaving this constructor     
  vmDbg_TestExceptionsHandling('Jira790TestCase.3'); // <-- sometimes it crashes here
end;
```

The idea of this test function: just to raise exceptions as usual and confirm if `try ... except` works as expected.

So, the problem is: `try ... except` statements suddenly stop to work as expected. Instead of catching exceptions the application crashes with a message like this (when running in debugger):

> ```
> ---------------------------
> Debugger Fault Notification
> ---------------------------
> Project D:\testApp\testApp.exe faulted with message: 'application-defined exception 
> (code 0x0eedfade) at 0x756456e8'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
> ---------------------------
> OK   
> ---------------------------
> ```

When running normally (without debugger) it writes to Windows Events log messages like these:

> ```
> Faulting application name: testApp.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x2a425e19
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19724, time stamp: 0x5ec50c3e
> Exception code: 0x0eedfade
> Fault offset: 0x000156e8
> Faulting process id: 0xb98
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d89d1805403f55
> Faulting application path: D:\testApp\testApp.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
> Report Id: 43b9a57a-090b-11ed-8140-000c299851c5
> Faulting package full name: 
> Faulting package-relative application ID:
> ```

- I stepped through ASM code, validated a lot of stuff, confirmed that VMT of created objects are valid. But now I'm a bit stuck, because I'm not sure how exception handling is implemented in Borland Delphi 5 (or 7). Tried to use Google but it seems that nothing interesting on particular low-level details on how exceptions are implemented in Borland Delphi exists.

Could you please advise documentation materials on this topic? How can I manually track and check correctness of exception handling structures for Borland Delphi? What structures are created for exception handling, where exactly, and so on. I guess it should be somewhere on the stack, but I need a bit more details on it.

- This is a single threaded simple UI application. Just one form with a button. No additional threads in the background. Also I have not found any problems with heap memory integrity, so that is not broken RAM.
- Important: crashing only happens on Windows Server. So,

  - it works fine on Windows 7 and 10 (but pls note - on some editions of Windows 10 it also begin to crash, ex: on Win 10 2004 but on next edition - it no crash anymore)
  - but it crashes on Windows Server 2012, 2016, 2019.

  I tried to configure this app to run in different "compatibility modes" but that does not have any effect - it still crashes.

Comment: Can you make it a complete program to check for sure you isolated the problem? Nobody knows what `EVmDllTestException` really is - you could have at least written `type EVmDllTestException= Exception;`

Comment: Ok. I replaced EVmDllTestException with Exception - nothing changed. And you were right - that is defined as type EVmDllTestException= Exception;

Comment: Test without the DLL, which seems to raise an exception. See [KernelBase.dll 0x0EEDFADE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62267856/4299358) and [0x0eedfade in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16602756/4299358) and [0x0eedfade in test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40754343/4299358) and [0x0eedfade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32073849/4299358) or [use the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+0x0eedfade).

Comment: Exceptions raised in a DLL must be handled inside the DLL, not outside in the calling app!

Comment: DLL dos and don’ts by Rudy Velthuis:  http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html

Comment: @DelphiCoder that is true for plain DLLs. For BPLs, throwing and handling exceptions across the DLL boundary is OK.

Comment: Just FYI - exceptions from C++ DLL are perfectly catch by Delphi 5 and 7 - they are mapped to EExternalException exception class and can be handled normally. 
Also - this app was working fine on all client Windows OS'es - 2000, XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10... but then suddenly it begins to crash on all Windows Server OS'es - 2008, 2012, 2016, etc. So, this is very old application which was worked fine all these years.

Comment: Reminder: your question nowhere explicitly says that exceptions **do occur in a DLL** - the code makes it one possibility. You should write your own C++ DLL wrapping that DLL of interest and at the same time catching all exceptions. Just because it worked on client OSes doesn't make it valid/correct.

Comment: Yes, correct. I do not tell "that exceptions do occur in a DLL". I tell - maybe something was broken in exceptions handling structures, so I'm trying to figure out - what that could be and fix it. So, I need some documentation on implementation details for exceptions handling in Delphi 5/7 - the rest I can do by myself. Also please note - there were no exceptions inside DLL! All DLL API calls finished with success. Problem is that exe-app no longer able to handle own exceptions normally.

Comment: FYI: In KernelBase.dll - it crash in RaiseException API function.
So, function address = $756456A0, it crash at $756456E8, which means - it crash at KERNELBASE.RaiseException+$48 location (on mov ecx,[ebp+$54] asm command)

Answer (score 0):

As discovered there was wrong call-specification for 6 of 300 API functions in VM dll (only 1 of these API functions was frequently used). These functions were compiled with C++ default call-specification - **cdecl** (instead of **stdcall** as defined in application code). So, all this was because of broken stack.
Seems that is only the reason why exception handlers fail to work as expected...

After I fixed and rebuild our VM dll - all things begin to work. At least I cannot find any crash issues anymore. All exceptions are catch and handled correctly now (both - exceptions inside C++ lib and exceptions in Delphi-compiled application exe).

The strange thing - 1st version of out VM lib was released at July 2003 and since that time this piece of code was not changed. So, all these years dll API function with *wrong call-specification* was working correctly on all client Windows OS'es. Seems there is some difference on how different Windows OS versions handling application stacks.

Comment: The reason that a Server edition might want to behave differently is the different type of workload.  On a desktop PC, you generally want to limp along and expect the user to notice the problem and save as much data as possible.  On a server, the stack corruption could be caused by a security vulnerability and there's likely no one watching closely, so if an attacker manages to start malicious code running, it could keep going for a long time.  Better for the service to crash, result in some log entries, and be automatically restarted by service manager.