# application-defined exception (code 0x0eedfade) after actual exception

Tags: delphi, exception, dll

I've got a piece of legacy code written in Delphi, long before I jointed the company and the behaviour of my IDE makes me doubt a lot of my own skills.

After loading a DLL and assigning the functions OpenDB, GetError and GetErrorStr from the DLL, this code gets called:

```
If @OpenDB <> nil then
begin
  DB_num := OpenDB((PAnsiChar(file)));
  if DB_num = -1 then
  begin
    err := GetError;
    ErrorString := GetErrorString(err);
    raise Exception.Create(ErrorString);
    Exit;
  end
end else
  Exit;
```

OpenDB returns -1 and GetErrorString returns an error message and the exception is raised. No big deal, faulty databases exist and errors can always happen. What gets me is, that after the exception is raised, "...application-defined exception (code 0x0eedfade) at ..." pops up. After that I get access violations.

Comment: Hard to comment without more context.

Comment: Most likely memory corruption.

Comment: Wait, so, after an exception gets raised, you see a popup saying an exception got raised? What else do you expect to have happen?

Comment: @MorganThrapp I don't mean the GUI  gives the exception message, but after the debugger informs about the exception I raise with the error string, the IDE throws an own exception "In Projekt XYZ trat ein Problem mit folgender Meldung auf: 'application-defined exception (code 0x0eedfade) at 0x74f94298'. Prozess angehalten. Mit Einzelne Anweisung oder Start fortsetzen." Sorry, I don't know the English error message.

Comment: @S.Langhammer Right, that's the IDE telling you that an exception was raised.

Comment: Check your exception handling. Any [unhandled Delphi exception](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8151620/11480) will produce the code `0x0eefade`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that you are raising a Delphi exception across module boundaries into a piece of code that does not know how to handle Delphi exceptions.  `0x0EEDFADE` is the value that the Delphi `raise` statement passes to the `dwExceptionCode` parameter of the Win32 [`RaiseException()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552.aspx) function.  Only the Delphi and C++Builder RTLs know how to handle those kind of exceptions.  You must never raise an exception across module boundaries, because one module does not know if another module can handle it.  Different modules can be written in different languages/frameworks.

Comment: Indeed. If possible, [NEVER LET AN EXCEPTION ESCAPE A DLL](http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-cppobjs.html#exceptions).