# Create 0x0eedfade exception in test project

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have an application that is crashing with 0x0eedfade exception. 
This exception is reported in windows event logs, but is not caught by the applications exception handler. To better understand how this may be happening, I would like to create a test app which produces the same error.

The answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073849/application-defined-exception-code-0x0eedfade-after-actual-exception) suggests it is caused by raising a Delphi exception across module boundaries. In light of this I created a Delphi library which throws an exception and a Delphi exe that calls the library.

*Library code*

```
library Project2;
uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;
{$R *.RES}
procedure DllException; export;
begin
  raise Exception.Create('Library exception');
end;

exports DllException;

begin
end.
```

*Program code*

```
unit test;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure AppOnException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
  public
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

  procedure DllException; external 'Project2.dll'

implementation
{$R *.DFM}
procedure TForm1.AppOnException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(E.Message));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException := AppOnException;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DllException;
end;
end.
```

I was expecting this to produce a 0x0eedfade exception and the program to crash. What happens is an error message displays essentially saying "Library exception" and the program carries on.

How can I create a test application that produces a 0x0eedfade exception?

Comment: Read Remy's answer to the linked question more carefully, where it refers to *that cannot handle Delphi exceptions*. Clearly, Delphi code can handle Delphi exceptions, because it's *Delphi code*.

Comment: @KenWhite So if I understand that correct. It would normally be caused by a non Delphi application calling a Delphi dll which raises an exception. How then would a Delphi application crash with this exception?

Comment: The relevant portion: *The error message means that you are **raising a Delphi exception across module boundaries into a piece of code that does not know how to handle Delphi exceptions.*** That *piece of code* can be in a Windows system DLL, a third party DLL, a COM library, or other *piece of code that does not know how to handle Delphi exceptions*.

Comment: More importantly, the code receiving the raised exception should be run in a **non-Delphi, non-C++Builder** process, since their Delphi-based RTL knows how to handle `0x0EEDFADE` exceptions, even if raised across module boundaries. So, you are not going to be able to test this in a Delphi project, unless you allow the main thread to NOT catch the exception at all so it can escape the process. Which is not the case in your example. An exception raised in a UI event handler is caught by the main message loop and sent to the `TApplication.OnException` event and/or displayed in a popup dialog.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I feel I understand that, but my app (real one, not test) is written in Delphi so would it need to be a Delphi callback function for a Windows dll or handling a windows message or something? Or should this still get caught by exception handling.

Comment: @energ1ser: I think you missed the point I was trying to make. SEH-based exception handling (which is what Delphi uses) is per-thread, and the main UI thread of a Delphi app has default exception handlers in strategic places in the RTL, including the main message loop. It doesn't matter where the exception comes from if it matches what the exception handlers are looking for. You have a Delphi DLL raising a Delphi exception into Delphi exception handlers, so it is going to be handled. Try raising a Delphi exception outside of `Application.Run()` and you should see the crash you want.

Comment: For the record, cross module exceptions are still dubious even with Delphi on both sides. Exception allocated by one module, destroyed by the other module. That's no good if the heap isn't shared. Further, if the compiler versions differ, the class layout may differ. To make this work you need to use runtime packages.

Comment: Read this: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html#exceptions and heed it.